# Set environment variable from file in pod spec

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to set environment variable from file in pod spec.
I don't have option to use configmap or secret.

I am fetching some dynamic values in init container and sharing the file with pod using volume and volume mount .

```
filename -> /var/file.env
username: test 
password: password
```

I cannot use "source file.env" as it java alpine image and already have entrypoint defined in image.

Is there a way to use something like

```
name: Username
      valueFrom: ??
```

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to overwrite the entrypoint by sourcing the env file and then using containers original entrypoint?

Comment: `source` is a non-standard vendor shell extension, but the POSIX shell spec includes `.` which is very similar, and it's supported in Alpine and the shells on non-Linux Unices.  You do probably still have to modify the image's startup sequence to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a secret. here official documentation. https://kubernetes.io/es/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

In your case follow this.

```
echo -n 'admin' > ./username.txt
echo -n 'password' > ./password.txt
```

then execute the following command.

```
kubectl create secret generic db-user-pass --from-file=./username.txt --from-file=./password.txt
```

To show your newly added secret.

```
kubectl get secrets
```

To see what you have done in details follow the next command.

```
kubectl describe secrets/db-user-pass
```

remember when using the enviroment variables stored you need to call the secret by it's name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

Comment: How did `db-user-pass` become `mysecret`?

Comment: because you gave it a generic name look on the kubectl command.

Comment: The secret name given when `kubectl create secret` is `db-user-pass`. So in the pod's yaml it should be `secretName: db-user-pass`. Yes, you can use something else for the `name` but `secretName` must point to the actual name of the secret.